# SQL Server stored procedure write/read file from host server directory

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to read/write a file in a directory on the host server. Actually I don't know how to give dynamic path. In asp.net, I do it like `~/dir/blah` and in jQuery it is like `../dir/blah` but I don't know similar thing in a stored procedure.

I want do this in my stored procedure.

This is what I need to do but in my case on the host, but don't know how to generate `@pathofpic` since I need to upload the project on the host server of client

```
set @pic_qry = 'insert into [dbo].[trainer_pic]([pic_trainer_fk],[pic_img_x]) select '+CAST(@given_tnrID as varchar(max))+',BulkColumn from openrowset(Bulk '''+@pathofpic+''',Single_Blob) as picture'
```

Answer (score 0):

The directories `~/dir/blah` and `../dir/blah` are relative directories, first from the home directory of the user and second from current directory. If you know the full path of the file, you can always use that for `@pathofpic`. There's no need to have relative paths. What the path is, of course depends on your setup.

Comment: in my system ofcurse i know the path but for host i dont have any idea thats why i need relative path within stored procedure

Comment: What then writes the files there? Somehow I don't understand how you can have files in a directory that you don't know where it is...